# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught phpmailerException: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php

I am a noob in PHP, I don't know much.

i cannot login or move past the verification page link sent to my email. i have checked the  files that are deprecated but apparently the changes have already been made. it never behaved this way before below is the error logs in my public_html folder

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php(1542): PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array)
#1 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php(1337): PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Mon, 25 M...', 'This is a multi...')
#2 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php(1215): PHPMailer->postSend()
#3 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/regver.php(29): PHPMailer->send()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php on line 1699
[25-May-2020 20:05:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught phpmailerException: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. in /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php:1699
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php(1542): PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array)
#1 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php(1337): PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Mon, 25 M...', 'This is a multi...')
#2 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php(1215): PHPMailer->postSend()
#3 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/regver.php(29): PHPMailer->send()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php on line 1699
[25-May-2020 20:05:42 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead in /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/PHPMailerAutoload.php on line 45
[25-May-2020 20:05:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught phpmailerException: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. in /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php:1699
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php(1542): PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array)
#1 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php(1337): PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Mon, 25 M...', 'This is a multi...')
#2 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/class.phpmailer.php(1215): PHPMailer->postSend()
#3 /home2/advance2/public_html/inc/regver.php(29): PHPMailer->send()
#4 {main}
```

this is the part of the class.phpmailer.php that supposedly has an error.

```
    }
            if ($this->SMTPAuth) {
                if (!$this->smtp->authenticate(
                    $this->Username,
                    $this->Password,
                    $this->AuthType,
                    $this->Realm,
                    $this->Workstation
                )
                ) {
                    throw new phpmailerException($this->lang('authenticate'));
                }
            }
            return true;
        } catch (phpmailerException $exc) {
            $lastexception = $exc;
            $this->edebug($exc->getMessage());
            // We must have connected, but then failed TLS or Auth, so close connection nicely
            $this->smtp->quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What link sent to your email are you talking about? If phpmailer can’t connect to the SMTP you have configured here, then how would it send you any such mail in the first place?

Comment: Verification link

Comment: And that is send by the the same site, using the same phpmailer and configuration? When does the error actually occur then?

Comment: @CBroe probably when I click the verification link. Because It doesn't get verified and when I try to login it takes me back to the verification link page

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the SMTP authentication fails. Please check the configuration if you have configured a valid entry.